# css to make imageicon movedown with text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do like this,

when text having only single line 'x' icon also on same line but when text having two or more line 'x' icon also want to move on last line.

http://jsfiddle.net/V6H67/

```
1)

This is text to test         x

2)

This is test to test
this is second line          x
```

i am trying this,

```
css:

.leftalign {
   float: left;
 }
.rightalign{
 float: right;
 }

.mainWrap{
  width: 100%;
}

.removeWrap {
  width: 100%;
}

Html:
<div class="mainWrap">
   <div class="title leftalign">
      This is test to test
      this is second line  
        <div class="removeWrap rightalign">
          <a href="" class="CloxeIcon">x</a>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

By using this i am getting,

```
This is test to test this is second line this is 
third line this is fourth line this is fifth line new 
line                                                x
```

Problem is 'x' icon is now below 'new'word

i want to like this,all text should in left side and icon at right side

```
This is test to test this second line this  is 
third line this is fourth line this is fifth 
line new line                                    x
```

Comment: Maybe you want this: http://jsfiddle.net/V6H67/3/ The position from bottom will be equal to the font-size.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of using relative and absolute positioning like the following.
`<div class="mainWrap">`
`This is test to test`
`this is second line`
`<a href="" class="CloxeIcon">x</a>`
`</div>`

and the css
`.mainWrap{`
`position: relative;`
`}`
`.mainWrap a{`
`position: absolute;`
`display: block;`
`bottom: 0;`
`right: 0;`
`}`

Answer (score 0):

Like that? **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V6H67/4)**

```
<div class="two_columns">

    <div class="left_column">
        This is test to test<br>
        This is another line
    </div>
    <div class="right_column">
        x
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.two_columns>div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: left;
}
.right_column {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> HTML:

```
<div class="mainWrap">
    <div class="title leftalign">
    This is test to test this is second line 
    </div> 
    <div class="removeWrap rightalign">
       <a href="" class="CloxeIcon">x</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

> CSS:

```
.leftalign {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 125px;
}
.rightalign{
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: bottom;
}
.mainWrap{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to figure out how many lines the text takes up is a fail, at least directly.

You could hack a functional solution, though, based on the height of the element... the more lines there are, the taller the element will become.

You could do this in a few ways... but this seems the simplest.

try:

```
.mainWrap
{
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This allows absolutely positioning the icon, like this:

```
.rightalign
{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:25%;
}
```

This worked on my test... you can also, of course, adjust the 'top' position to your liking.

It also overwrites the effect of .rightalign on the icon, which is why right:0 is set.

A few minor notes from your code...

...if you want to force those to be two lines, you might add a br between them.

... also, this sends the icon to the far right of the screen.  This is because you have not explicitly set a width on the div that these are contained in.  If you are unsure of how wide the div will be, you can also set these via max-width.

Hope it helps.